# Проверка отчётов на количество символов

Tags: регулярные-выражения, google-forms

Не могу понять как сделать проверку ответов в гугл формах на количество символов "|". Например мне нужно чтобы в одном ответе была проверка на один символ "|", в другом ответе проверка на 3 таких символа.
Потыкал, попробовал, получилось сделать проверку только для одного символа

```
([|]{1})
```

Как сделать проверку на количество таких символов, в зависимости от вопроса? Например на 3, 4, 5 символов?
Символы служат для разделения какого-либо текста. То есть правильный ответ на первый вопрос должен быть: текст | текст. Ответ на второй вопрос: текст | текст | текст | текст и т.п. Мне нужно избежать других символов и настроить проверку для этого. То есть ответ: "текст - текст" не должен приниматься, а ответ "текст | текст" - должен быть верным.
Эксперты, помогите)

Comment: Для чего ты там написал 1 в фигурные скобках?

Comment: Бродил по интернету и нашёл только такой способ, понимаю, что он неверный и неправильный, поэтому и обращаюсь за помощью

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Меняю ответ согласно комментария:

```
[^|]*(?:\|[^|]*){3}
```

Так же должно быть установлено полное совпадение строки.
Валидным для данного выражения будет любая строка содержащая в себе три символа пайп.
Регулировать количество совпадений нужно меня квантификатор.
`[^|]*` - ноль и более символов отличных от пайп
`(?:...)` - не захватываемая группа, нужна для квантификации
`\|[^|]*` - одиночный символ пайп после которого идут ноль и более символов отличных от пайп
`{3}` - квантификатор группы, 3 совпадения предыдущего шаблона

Comment: Я видимо неправильно сформулировал проблему. Символы служат для разделения какого-либо текста. То есть правильный ответ на первый вопрос должен быть: текст | текст. Ответ на второй вопрос: текст | текст | текст | текст и т.п. Мне нужно избежать других символов и настроить проверку для этого. То есть ответ: "текст - текст" не должен приниматься, а ответ "текст | текст" - должен быть верным.

Comment: Для этого выбран неверный путь. Если я введу просто а|б|в, то засчитается правильный ответ, поскольку | встречается три раза, а что там между ними написано никак не проверяется.

Comment: Спасибо большое, помогло.

Answer (score 0):

Всего-то

```
(\|.*){3}
```

а мне теперь ещё 21 символ придумывать к этим 9...

Answer (score 0):

Вам, наверное, проще будет считать не сами разделители, а был ли дан полный ответ с разделителем `текст | текст`. И потом сравнить номер вопроса и количество полученных групп, если они совпадают, то ответ принимается. Тогда ловим полную группу
`([\w ]+\|[\w ]+)`. Если символ подчеркивания `_` вам также следует исключить, то замените `\w` на `[a-zA-Z0-9]`. И так как первый ответ идет без разделителя в начале, то делаем выбор:

```
 ^([\w ]+\|[\w ]+)|\|([\w ]+\|[\w ]+)
```

При правильном форматировании ответа количество полученных групп, будет совпадать с номером вопроса.